# How to merge result from $lookup with subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Consider the following toy example:

Collection `shops`

```js
{
  "products": [
    { id: "abc", price: 20.5 },
    { id: "abd", price: 34.0 }
  ]
}
```

Collection `products`

```js
{
  _id: "abc",
  name: "Apple"
}
```

Running the following query...

```js
db.shops.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "products.id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "product_info"
    }
  }
])
```

returns...

```js
[{
  "products": [
    { id: "abc", price: 20.5 },
    { id: "abd", price: 34.0 }
  ],
  "product_info": [
    { _id: "abc", name: "Apple" },
    { _id: "abd", name: "Orange" }

  ]
}]
```

Is there a way to "merge" `products` and `product_info` to get the following?

```js
[{
  "products": [
    { id: "abc", price: 20.5, name: "Apple" },
    { id: "abd", price: 34.0, name: "Orange" }
  ],
}]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.shops.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "products.id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "products.name"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$products.name" },
  { $addFields: { "products.name": "$products.name.name" }},
  { $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    products: {
      $push: "$products"
    }
  }}
])
```